# How to use a while loop to keep looping until condition met with user input kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Using a while loop to keep looping until condition is met.

**When pin correct:** Displays no message, exits program.

**When user inputs wrong pin:** Displays correct error message **Pin is incorrect**, Keeps promting user for input and keeps displaying **Pin is incorrect**.

**When user inputs a non integer data type:** Displays correct error message **Pin is incorrect**, Keeps promting user for input and keeps displaying **Pin is incorrect**.

Here is my code

```
fun main() {
    println("Create PIN: ")
    val pin = readln().toIntOrNull()

    println("Enter PIN: ")
    val input = readln().toIntOrNull()

    while (input != pin) {
        if (input == pin) {
            println("PIN is correct")
        }
        else{
            println("Pin is incorrect")
            readln().toIntOrNull()
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: I needed to walk away, was feeling like smashing my head against my keyboard haha. Ended up getting it working.**

Here's the fix

```
fun main() {
println("Create PIN: ")
val pin = readln().toIntOrNull()

println("Enter PIN: ")
var input = readln().toIntOrNull()

while (input != pin)
{
    println("PIN is incorrect")
    input = readln().toIntOrNull()
}
if (input == pin){
    println("PIN is correct")
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already solved it, but just want to share an alternate design pattern you could use in this situation. A `while(true)` loop keeps running until you call `break` inside it. It can lead to less code repetition in cases like what you're doing here.

Notice you only have to use `readln().toIntOrNull()` once instead of twice, and the `input` variable becomes unnecessary:

```
fun main() {
    println("Create PIN: ")
    val pin = readln().toIntOrNull()

    println("Enter PIN: ")
    while (true) {
        if (readln().toIntOrNull() == pin) {
            println("PIN is correct")
            break
        }
        println("PIN is incorrect")
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it thank you

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to capture newly typed pin. And since you are changing value of the variable you need to use `var` instead of `val`

```
var input = readln().toIntOrNull()
```

instead of

```
    else{
        println("Pin is incorrect")
        readln().toIntOrNull()
    }
```

use

```
else{
        println("Pin is incorrect")
        input = readln().toIntOrNull()
    }
```

Comment: Vojin not sure what you mean by capture newly typed pin? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Like i wrote in the answer. Same thing you did. you were not saving newly entered input from user

Comment: Oh I get ya now, was readlining to nothing, but with the edit, readlines to the input?